# How to run a script file from CMD from am already open program

Tags: cmd.exe

I use Dymola program for modeling and simulation. I have a script file that I want to run in Dymola. I want this done from Command line, in a way that it accesses Dymola that is already open (with certain libraries already loaded). To explain further, my requirement is:

1. I have Dymola already open on my computer
2. I call Dymola from command prompt to run a script file (normally this would be like:-

   dymola scriptfile.mos

in command prompt.)

3. But instead of opening new instance of program, it should pass this run request to already open Dymola.

I need this because of 2 reasons:-
1. I want to run particular model with different parameter in loop.
2. I am expecting to change script file itself in in a loop on higher level.
3. Most importantly though, new instance of dymola requires reloading of all libraries which is time consuming and I want to avoid it.

(I want to do this specifically from command line not from within Dymola.) 
Is this possible. IF yes, then how can I do it?

Comment: If Dymola supports multiple instances you could try finding instance of Dymola and point the script at the instance.... just shooting in  dark :)

Comment: I want to run script more that 20 times, if it opened dymola for each case and tries to load library each time, then whole point of batch run is lost along with large number of GUI windows of dymola open.